# How can i solve this issue with average num in array

Tags: c, arrays, average, function-definition

I want to print average number of the elements in array using function

This is my attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100
void avgee();
int main()
{
    int a[MAX_SIZE],n,i;
    double avg=0,sum=0;
    printf("Enter the numbers of average:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    avgee(a,n);
    return 0;
}
void avgee(int a[MAX_SIZE],int n)
{
    int i,sum,avg;
    printf("Average number is:");
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+a[i];
        avg=sum/n;
    }
    printf("%f",avg)
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work, can anyone assist?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RWAGuuGU

Comment: There are several things wrong. You don't initialise `sum`. You find the average inside the loop instead of outside (not actually a fault), and you index the arrays from `1` to `<= n` when they should be from `0` to `< n`;. You define `avg` as `int` when it should be `double`. You need to cast the `sum` before dividing.

Comment: Please take note of compiler warnings, and there is an error due to a  `;` missing from the last-but-one line.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of the function should be `void avgee(int a[MAX_SIZE],int n);`, not `void avgee();`. Additionally, you also forgot to add `;` after `printf("%f",avg)`

Comment: I missed the prototype one.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function prototype should be placed before main. In this case the compiler can check whether the function is called correctly.

The function shall not output any message. It shall return the average value. It is the caller of the function that decides what message if any to output.

The function.should be declared the following way

```
double average( const int a[], size_t n );
```

and defined like

```
double average( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }

    return n == 0 ? 0.0 : sum / n;
}
```

Pay attention that indices of arrays start from 0.

So in main you should write

```
printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

printf( "Average number is: %f\n", average( a, n ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE    100

double average( const int a[], size_t n );

int main(void) 
{
    int a[MAX_SIZE];

    size_t n = MAX_SIZE;

    printf( "Enter the numbers of average: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    if ( MAX_SIZE < n ) n = MAX_SIZE;

    printf( "Enter the numbers:\n" );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d", &a[i] );
    }       

    printf( "Average number is: %.1f\n", average( a, n ) );

    return 0;
}

double average( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }

    return n == 0 ? 0.0 : sum / n;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the numbers of average: 10
Enter the numbers:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Average number is: 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Average `avg` should be declared as a double as `printf("%f",avg)`.

Your loop should iterate only upto `<n` scenario and calculating average should be out of loop. 
Like,

```
avg=sum/n;
printf("%f",avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void avgee();

int main() {
  int n, i;
  printf("Enter the numbers of average: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int a[n];
  printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
  for(i = 0;i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }
  avgee(a, n);
  return 0;
}

void avgee(int a[], int n) {
  int i, sum = 0;
  for(i = 0;i < n; i++) {
    sum += a[i];
  }
  printf("Average number is: %.2f", sum * 1.0 / n);
}
```